# What does render do with instance variables?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I use a scaffold to generate a Foo model/controller, my controller has a default create action that will `render :new` if `@foo.save` returns false.

What happens to my @foo object when I `render :new`?

My stock **new.html.erb** view refers to `@foo.errors`, which makes me think that it reuses the @foo from my create action (rather than create a new object with `@foo = Foo.new` again in the new method). Is this not the case?

I'm worrying about this because I want to reuse this convention in a new namespaced controller (everything else appearing equal), but I get nil for @foo when `render :new` happens. It appears it's neither reusing the Foo object, nor creating a new one. So I'm trying to understand render better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render` doesn't call the *action* `new`, it just processes the file new.html.erb (or whatever) and sends it to the browser. The `@foo` instance variable created in your create action is used when rendering that template, that's why, if the record fails to save, the when the form is rendered the user's information is still present in the form fields (assuming the form is set up correctly).

If you want to start a whole new request with a fresh `@foo` instance variable, you can `redirect_to :new` instead of rendering, or just manually set `@foo = Foo.new` before the call to `render`.

If you have a 'new namespaced controller', that's (self-evidently) not the same controller. It's not clear exactly what you're doing from the question, but if you're setting `@new` in one controller and then trying to access it from another controller... that's never going to work.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation

> If you want to render the view that corresponds to a different template within the same controller, you can use render with the name of the view:

So, `render` is used to render the view template and does not actually call the action. The name of the view  to render can either be a `string` or `symbol`.

```
render 'new' # renders new.html.erb

render :new  # renders new.html.erb
```

So, in your case, when `render :new` in the `create` action is executed, all the controller does is renders the `new.html.erb` passing on the instance variable `@foo`from the `create` action. That is why you're able to see the `@foo.errors.full_messages` in the view when saving a record fails because `@foo` refers to the invalid object.

In short, `render` just renders the template you specify and does not call an action recreating an object.

The parameter that you pass to the `render` method need not be the `action` name. You can also pass the path to the actual view file.

For the whole list of valid arguments, see section 2.2.4 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Hope this helps.